# Why is the qr code not redirecting to the url?

Tags: php

I installed this dynamic qr generator that I found on github using free domain and hosting. After the QR is created, I scan it, it does not redirect me to the URL and I get a 404 not found error. Please help me with this problem. I have homework.

https://github.com/giandonatoinverso/PHP-Dynamic-Qr-code.git

read.php

```
<?php
/**
* PHP Dynamic QR code
*
* @author Giandonato Inverso <info@giandonatoinverso.it>
* @copyright Copyright (c) 2020-2021
* @license https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT MIT License
* @link https://github.com/giandonatoinverso/PHP-Dynamic-Qr-code
* @version 1.0
*/

include 'qrcode/config/config.php';

//Get DB instance. function is defined in config.php
$db = getDbInstance();
$get_id = htmlspecialchars($_GET['id'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); // I take the id through the GET method

$state = $db->query("SELECT state FROM dynamic_qrcodes WHERE identifier='$get_id'");
$link = $db->query("SELECT link FROM dynamic_qrcodes WHERE identifier='$get_id'");

$update = $db->query("UPDATE dynamic_qrcodes SET scan=scan+1 WHERE identifier='$get_id'");
    
    if($state[0]['state'] == 'enable'){
        echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL='.$link[0]['link'].'" />'; // Page refresh with the link obtained
        echo 'Loading...'; // You can include a custom page to display during the redirect
    }
    else
        echo 'Disabled link';
?>
```

Comment: I suggest this library instead: https://github.com/chillerlan/php-qrcode

Comment: But what you suggest is static qr encoder. i need dynamic qr coder.

Comment: What do you mean it's static? That library has everything you might want.

Comment: This is ( github.com/chillerlan/php-qrcode ) static qr coder. Look at. static & Dynamic qr codes

Comment: A QR code itself does not redirect. The URL you are calling could get redirected, but that is completely independent from the code. How do you define the difference between a static and a dynamic QR code?